# Finding the values of a

Tags: calculus, polynomials

What are the values of $a$ for which all the roots of the equation $x^4-4x^3-8x^2+a=0$ are real?

My approach:

On differentiating the polynomial and equating it to $0$, we get $(x)(x+1)(x-4)=0$. So, the derivative of the given equation has all the three roots real. Now, what should be the binding condition so as to find the interval in which $a$ lies?

Comment: where is $a$ in your polynomial :O

Comment: I am sorry. I was still trying to solve it while writing it here.

Comment: Differentiating with respect to $a$ helps us to identify the turning points of function $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 - 8x^2$.  In order to hit four real roots, how should $a$ be chosen in relation to those turning points (local maximum, local minima)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  If you [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E4-4x%5E3-8x%5E2%20from%20-2%20to%205) the polynomial with $a=0$ (you may need to change the range to see everything) you see it comes down from $+\infty$, hits a local minimum, goes up to a local maximum, hits the global minimum, and rises to $+\infty$  Changing $a$ positions the $x$ axis.  You want to make sure the $x$ axis cuts the graph in four places.

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x)=x^4-4x^3-8x^2$$$$=x^2(x^2-4x-8)$$ we get the roots $0$,$2(1+\sqrt{3})$,$2(1-\sqrt{3})$.
also as $x\to\infty$, $f(x)\to\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$,$f(x)\to\infty$.therefore the given function decreases from $-\infty$ and starts to increase at a value of $x$ between $2(1-\sqrt{3 })$and $0$ ,then just grazes at $x=0$, further decreases till an $x$ between $0$ and $2(1+\sqrt{3})$ and further keeps on increasing.

therefore the given function can be made to have $4$ roots only if you raise the function upwards by the help of a constant. here this constant is $a$.   ie   $$a>0$$